# Set identity problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be any sets. Prove the following identity using set identities.
>   $$\overline{\left(A \cap B\right) \cup \left(\overline{A} \cap C\right)} = \left(A \cap \overline{B}\right) \cup \left(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}\right) $$

I have reduced the LHS down to :
$$\left(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}\right) \cup \left(\overline{B} \cap \overline{C}\right) \cup \left(A \cap \overline{B}\right)$$
But I have no idea how to simplify it further.

Comment: what is the meaning of the $\overline{A}$?

Comment: @kide: Presumably the complement of $A$ (or, if you're sensitive to foundations, the relative complement of $A$ within some other sufficiently large set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just note that
$$(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C})\cup(A \cap \overline{B}) \supseteq
(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}\cap \overline{B})\cup (A \cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) =(\overline{A} \cup A)\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}=\overline{B}\cap \overline{C}.$$
So your reduced LHS is equal to the RHS.

Comment: How did you know or derive that
$$(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}\cap \overline{B})\cup (A \cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}) \subseteq (\overline{A} \cap \overline{C})\cup(A \cap \overline{B})$$

Comment: Because $(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C})\supseteq
(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}\cap \overline{B})$ and $(A \cap \overline{B})\supseteq
(A \cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C})$

Comment: Yea, so basically these subset relations for union and intersection are a bit confusing.
Basically, $$A \subseteq A \cup B$$ and $$ A \supseteq A \cap B$$ right?

Comment: @Light Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}) \cup (\overline{B} \cap A) \cup (\overline{B} \cap \overline{C}) =$$

$$(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}) \cup (\overline{B} \cap A) \cup (\overline{B} \cap \overline{C} \cap A) \cup (\overline{B} \cap \overline{C} \cap \overline{A})  = $$

$$(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}) \cup (\overline{A} \cap \overline{C} \cap \overline{B})  \cup (\overline{B} \cap A)  \cup (\overline{B}  \cap A \cap \overline{C})= $$

$$(\overline{A} \cap \overline{C})\cup (\overline{B} \cap A) $$